# How to reverse One-Hot Encoding of labels for evaluation of ML/DL model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

This issue has been mentioned a few times here on Stackoverflow, but none provided the solution for the problem/error I'm currently facing.

Currently my *y* of the dataset that I use as labels had to be transformed using One-Hot Encoding so that my Deep Learning network/model could handle it as a *categorical_crossentropy*.

But now the problem arises that for the evaluation of my data, it needs the original labels again for the prediction of y.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

keypoints = pd.read_csv('keypoints.csv')

X = keypoints.iloc[:,1:76]
y = keypoints.iloc[:,-1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=y)
```

Here y is a list of 3 different labels, let's say A,B and C with a shape of (63564, 1)

So using the One-Hot encoding I was able to split it up:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
y = ohe.fit_transform(y[:,None]).toarray()
```

The new y here has a shape of (63564, 3) and looks like:

```
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

After running my Deep Learning network I want to evaluate it by using:

```
......
#Evaluation and such
y_pred = model.predict(X_test, verbose=0)
y_classes = model.predict_classes(X_test, verbose=0)

#Reduce to 1D
y_pred = y_pred[:, 0]
y_classes = y_classes[:, 0]

#Confution Matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_classes))

#Accuracy: (tp + tn) / (p + n)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_classes)
print('Accuracy: %f' % accuracy)
#Precision tp / (tp + fp)
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_classes)
print('Precision: %f' % precision)
#Recall: tp / (tp + fn)
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_classes)
print('Recall: %f' % recall)
#F1: 2 tp / (2 tp + fp + fn)
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_classes)
print('F1 score: %f' % f1)
```

But ofcourse this won't accept the 0 and 1 as labels:

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of unknown and
>   continuous-multioutput targets

So my question is

> How do i reverese the One-Hot Encoded labels so that I can run the
>   evaluation of my DL model?

Answer (score 3):

You probably will need `inverse_transform` as documented in the [examples section of sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
>>> X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
>>> enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 4]]).toarray()
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> enc.inverse_transform([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
array([['Male', 1],
       [None, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I'm unable to get this to work.
Because i apply my One-Hot Encoding on my *y* before its fed to the the *train_test_split* and when I give my *y* back to the *inverse_transform* the dimensions for the confusion matrix do not match:
`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12713, 63564]`
And giving the *inverse_transform* the *y_test* as input gives the following error:
`ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argmax` to convert probabilities to categorical decisions:

```
y_test_classes = y_test.argmax(1)
y_pred_classes = y_pred.argmax(1)

print(confusion_matrix(y_true=y_test_classes, y_pred=y_pred_classes, labels=['A', 'B', 'C']))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm kind of confused by the naming of the first two lines since they are not reused in the print confusion matrix line?
Because I still get the same error when applying the above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, unfortunately I still get an error **ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass targets.** -
The output of *y_test_classes* and *y_pred_classes* is as follows: *y_test_classes* --> `[[0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] ... [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]]` -
*y_test_classes.shape* --> `(12713, 3)` - *y_pred_classes* --> `[2 2 0 ... 0 0 2]`
y_pred_classes.shape --> `(12713,)`

Answer (score 0):

```
y_classes = np.argmax(y_test_4, axis=1)


y_classes = model_4.predict_classes(x_test_4, verbose=0)
y_classes =  np.reshape(yhat_classes_4, (-1, 1))

y_classes= y_classes[:, 0]
 
# accuracy: (tp + tn) / (p + n)
accuracy_4 = accuracy_score(y_test_classes_4, y_classes)
print('Accuracy: %f' % accuracy_4)
# precision tp / (tp + fp)
precision_4 = precision_score(y_test_classes_4, y_classes)
print('Precision: %f' % precision_4)
# recall: tp / (tp + fn)
recall_4 = recall_score(y_test_classes_4, y_classes)
print('Recall: %f' % recall_4)
# f1: 2 tp / (2 tp + fp + fn)
f1_4 = f1_score(y_test_classes_4, y_classes)
print('F1 score: %f' % f1_4)
```

Use this. You want to first convert your one hot encoded data using argmax function to compare your predictions.'
Coming to the predictions part , you want to convert your 1D array to a 2D array as stated in line 3